# Way to configure WordPress FTP plugin downloads with Amazon webservices key pair security?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, key-pair

I'm trying to set up a WordPress site from an Amazon EC2 instance, and unfortunately I can't seem to get the FTP plugin downloads and so on running because Amazon requires that I use a keypair.

What are recommendation for how to configure FTP on Ubuntu to open a public container for uploads?

Comment: the only recommendation one can give on enabling ftp to an ec2 instance is: dont do it

Comment: Yeah I just realized that was a pretty dumb idea. Good advice :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Menu *Edit (Preferences)* → *Settings* → *Connection* → *SFTP*, Click "Add key file”
2. Browse to the location of your .pem file and select it.
3. A message box will appear asking your permission to convert the file into ppk format. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd>, then give the file a name and store it somewhere.
4. If the new file is shown in the list of Keyfiles, then continue to the next step. If not, then click "Add keyfile..." and select the converted file.
5. Menu *File* → *Site Manager*. Add a new site with the following parameters:

   Host: Your public DNS name of the Amazon EC2 instance, or the public IP address of the server

   Protocol: SFTP

   Logon Type: Normal

Comment: Is this for wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it using:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/*
```

But I'm not sure if this introduces additional security risk...

This seems to open up the entire HTML directory as a writable space.